# How to add React app as dependency in monorepo rushjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, monorepo

so I have 3 repositories in total in the rush js Monorepo.
App1
App2
App3
App 3 has Common components and Is accessible in App1 and App2.
The problem I am facing is that I now have to Add App2 as a Dependency in App1.
Can anyone help me with that? I am using Rush.js

Comment: you could use an iframe

Comment: can you elaborate, please?